# Can I group subelements in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Let's say I have a small html area like this:

```html
<div id="somecontainer">
   <h1>text</h1>
   <h2>text</h2>
   <h3>text</h3>
   <p>text</p>
</div>
```

And now I want to style several subelements of that container with CSS.
Currently I do it this way, but it looks more complicated than it might have to be:

```css
#somecontainer h1,#somecontainer h3,#somecontainer p { color:red; }
```

Is there any way I can kinda "group" those subelements for the CSS code, so I don't have to mention the container-ID `#somecontainer` three times?

I imagine maybe something like an operator which would make the syntax into something like `#somecontainer h1+h3+p` (for this example `+` would be assumed to be this operator). Is there such a thing in CSS?

Comment: In an ideal world: yes. See the `:any()` selector: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:any Or start using a CSS preprocessor engine (sass, less, etc)

Answer (score 4):

With pure CSS, this will target all direct children of #somecontainer:

```
#somecontainer > *
```

And then you can revert whatever you have set on the H2. For example

```
#somecontainer > * {color: red;}
#somecontainer > h2 {color: black};
```

But it's not a particularly efficient way of writing it.  I would stick to explicitly writing the classes, or ideally looking into using a preprocessor like [Less](http://lesscss.org/) or [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/), where you could write this:

```
#somecontainer {
    h1, h3, p {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

which would ouput what you ultimately want, this -

```
#somecontainer h1 {color: red;}
#somecontainer h3 {color: red;}
#somecontainer p {color: red;}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this include h2 of the original example? I don't want to style ALL subelements, just several of them.

Answer (score 1):

This is your core question:

> Is there any way I can kinda "group" those subelements for the CSS
>   code, so I don't have to mention the container-ID #somecontainer three
>   times?

Now, the grouping you envision does not really exist. But since your question is about reduction of CSS code, especially across multiple element types, then that is exactly the point of *classes* in CSS--something that can  be applied to multiple elements, but have a single, concise representation in CSS. Sometimes in trying to do fancy selections, we forget the simplicity of CSS.

So a somewhat generic class that could still be changed in value based off its container might be. You then have the choice of using that class to set one or the other of the elements, depending on how many you may have to set. Here's what I mean:

### Option 1 (More HTML change, Less CSS code)

**HTML**

```
<div id="somecontainer">
   <h1 class="setColor">text</h1>
   <h2>text</h2>
   <h3 class="setColor">text</h3>
   <p class="setColor">text</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#somecontainer .setColor {
  color: red;
}
```

### Option 2 (Less HTML change, slightly more CSS)

**HTML**

```
<div id="somecontainer">
   <h1>text</h1>
   <h2 class="setColor">text</h2>
   <h3>text</h3>
   <p>text</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#somecontainer {
  color: red;
}

#somecontainer .setColor {
  color: black;
}
```

**The point here is that "grouping" for styling is exactly what classes were meant for.** And should you ever decide to switch another element to that color, you add the class.