# css not working properly with <ul> and <li> items

Tags: html, css

I have a really weird situation where I'm trying to apply basic styling to `<ul>` and their `<li>` children but for some reason it's not working.

I have a `react` component which is rendering the following HTML:

```
<div class='header'>
    <ul class='links'>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Samples</li>
        <li>The collection</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and my CSS file looks like the following:

```
.links {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    li {
        padding: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}
```

The styling on the `<ul>` is applied but the styling on the `<li>`s is not being applied. However, if I reference the `<li>` tags outside like `.links > li` it's working.

Comment: That looks like SCSS not CSS by the way.

Comment: It's not Vanilla CSS.

Comment: your nesting is not ok this one is for SASS, SCSS, LESS and not CSS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't nest selectors in CSS like you can in LESS or SASS. Just expand your selector statement to `.links li`:

```css
.links {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.links li {
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

If you only wanted to target `li`s that are direct children of `.links` you'd use the [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors): `.links > li`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
.links {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.links > li {
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need this styling to apply only to the li inside of the .link class, then use the following:

```
.links {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.links li {
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure, that you are using SASS, SCSS or LESS.
If you are not, move your `li` styles outside the `.links` section.

Answer (score 0):

CSS doesn't allow nesting declarations, so you're initial example shouldn't work if it is in a .css file.  LESS and SASS both enable something close to what you're showing - there's a short explanation of that in this https://stackoverflow.com/a/15460328/2197085 answer.